# communication between asp.net page with silverlight application

Tags: .net

After authentication of login page in asp.net,it will redirect to silverlight page which exposes the methods using WCF service. when I copy that url and paste in browser,it again show the page of silverlight which I don't want, my requirement is when I will copy that url and paste in new browser instance,it should redirct to Login page in asp.net not to silverlight page.

Answer (score 0):

You could check on page load whether a user is authenticated or not. If they're aren't, redirect to login with another redirect after they've logged in successfully.

How you choose to track a user's authentication is up to you, there's plenty of options.